# inserting character in file , jython

Tags: jython

I have written a simple program where to read the first 4 characters and get the integer of it and read those many character and write xxxx after it . Although the program is working the only issues instead of inserting the character ,  its replacing.

```
file = open('C:/40_60.txt','r+')
i=0
while 1:
    char = int(file.read(4))
    if not char: break
    print file.read(char)
    file.write('xxxx')

print 'done'
file.close()
```

I am having issue with writing data . 
considering this is my sample data 
00146456135451354500107589030015001555854640020
and expected output is 
001464561354513545xxxx00107589030015001555854640020

but actually my above program is giving me this output

001464561354513545xxxx7589030015001555854640020
ie. xxxx overwrites 0010.

Please suggest.

Comment: What does `get the integer of it` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files do not support an "insert"-operation. To get the effect you want, you need to rewrite the whole file. In your case, open a new file for writing; output everything you read and *in addition*, output your 'xxxx'.

Comment: Its hitting the first character again rather than continuing the loop. Please suggest `code file = open('C:/40_60.txt','r') file_write=open('C:/40_60_output.txt','w') loop=0 while file: if file.read(4) == '': print 'loop done' break file.seek(-4) char= int(file.read(4)) file.seek(-4) file_write.write(file.read(4)) file_write.write(file.read(char)) file_write.write('xxxx') print file.read(4) loop+=1 if loop == 3: break print 'done' file_write.close() file.close() `

Comment: It's hard to read your code without the linebreaks. Do only a single read per iteration and store the return value in a variable (e.g. `x = file.read(4)`) and remove all seek calls. Also, there is nothing to read in `file_write` ...